# How can I get unique array values in PHP with different data types?

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
$array = array(true, null, false, true, false, null, false, null);
```

When executing `array_unique($array)` I receive the following result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  bool(true)
  [1]=>
  NULL
}
```

I'd expect the function to return `[true, null, false]`. Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Not with `array_unique`. You'd have to write a custom function. Are `true`, `false` and `null` the only three options that can appear in your input?

Comment: The null and false are same to they will be considered as null values while pushing in array.